# C's printf and fprintf(stdout,) are not printing

Tags: c, file-descriptor, printf

This is a bit of an odd one. My code wasn't outputting what I thought it should. I added some print statements at various stages to see where it was going wrong. Still nothing.
So I added a printf statement at the start of main. That's where I got really confused.

So I presumed something funny was happening with the file descriptors. I changed the `printf` to a `fprintf`. Still nothing. Printing to stderr with `fprintf` does work! Why is this happening?

Removing all of the body from main except the initial print statement and the return does print.

#### Code

```
int main(void) {
    fprintf(stdout, "STARTED!");
    //Create an Internet domain socket
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    //If this fails exit and print the error
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("Error %d, cannot create socket", errno);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("SOCKET CREATED!");

    //Creates a socket address
    struct sockaddr_in  addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    //Attempts to bind to the socket address, again prints to error if this fails.
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error %d, cannot bind", errno);
        return 1;
    }

    //Starts Listening for a client
    if (listen(sockfd, 1) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error %d, cannot listen", errno);
        return 1;
    }

    //If all is successful, server is operational
    while(1)
    {
        //Creates a file descripter for the connection
        int connfd;
        //And a socket address for the client
        struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;
        socklen_t cliaddrlen = sizeof(cliaddr);
        //If a connection attempt is made accepts it.
        connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &cliaddrlen);
        if (connfd == -1) {
            //If the connection fails print an error
            printf("Error %d, cannot accept connection", errno);
            continue;
        }

        //Otherwise process the request
        else {
            printf("CONNECTED!");
            char end;
            end = 1;
            while (end)
            {
                process_request(connfd);
                end = 0;
            }
        }
        close(connfd);

    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, and im sure the code itself can be improved so any improvement suggestions would also be awesome!

Comment: `command 1>&2`  will help if you want stdout to be not buffered as stderr.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Output is often buffered by the system. You can call fflush, but sometimes, depending on how the caching works, simply ending the output with a newline is sufficient. So try changing

```
fprintf(stdout, "STARTED!");
```

to

```
fprintf(stdout, "STARTED!\n");
```

And, if that doesn't help, to

```
fprintf(stdout, "STARTED!\n");
fflush(stdout)
```

(And stderr often isn't cached, as you want to see errors immediately.)

Finally, you will see output when the program finishes (as things are flushed then), which probably explains the rest of the behaviour.

Comment: Christ! How did i miss something so simple! Thanks Im now remembering having this same issue a year ago when I first used C.

Still, I don't understand why it worked with just the print statement in main, but not with the rest of the code there.

Comment: Sometimes the buffer gets flushed on its own, too.  I'm not sure how predictable it is unless you call `fflush` or put a `\n` in.