# Receive user&passwd from TCP socket and check

Tags: c, linux, string, sockets

I need to receive two data with TCP socket,and do verify in server.
when I used "strcmp" to compare two data.If it's correct,it should send server's networkconfig or send "Wrong" to client.

In my code.It works when I receive the right user&passwd,and send the data correctly.But when I receive wrong user& passwd,it doesn't do anything!!! And just hang there waiting for the right data sended.

ps. 0,0 is my defalut user&passwd.they are combined by "#" for sending

The following is my code

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>   
#include "xmlmgr.h"
void SetConfig(char *textS);
void ReadConfig(char *textR);
int main()
{
  int serverSocket;
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
  struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
  int port = 8000;
  int val = 1;
  int ret;
  fd_set set1;
  char textS[1024];
  char textR[1024];
  char account[32];
  char login[1024];
  int len;
  int sock;
  int clientAddrSize;
  struct timeval timeout;

  ReadConfig(textR);
  //  ** //this is my network config,it has been sended and received correctly in client server.**

  serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &val, sizeof(val));
  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY );
  memset(&(serverAddr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
  int sock_opt = 1;

  if (setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void*) &sock_opt,
      sizeof(sock_opt)) == -1)
  {
    printf(" false");
  }

  if (bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &serverAddr,
      sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0)
  {
    close(serverSocket);
    printf("Bad bind\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (listen(serverSocket, 5) < 0)
  {
    printf("Bad listen\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  clientAddrSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  sock = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &clientAddr,
      (socklen_t*) &clientAddrSize);
  FD_ZERO(&set1);
  FD_SET(sock, &set1);
  len = recv(sock, account, 1024, 0);
  // ** //receive user&passwd**

  while (1)
  {
    if (strcmp("0#0", account) == 0)
    {
      // ** //this is done correctly**
      printf("login!!\n");
      send(sock, &textR, strlen(textR) + 1, 0);
      printf("sended!!\n");

      sock = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &clientAddr,
          (socklen_t*) &clientAddrSize);
      recv(sock, &textS, 1024, 0);

      close(serverSocket);
      SetConfig(textS);
      system("/etc/init.d/network restart");

      exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
      // ** //Never do this part,this is my problem**
      strcpy(login, "Wrong!!!\n")
      send(sock, &login, strlen(login) + 1, 0);
      printf("wrong");
      sock = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &clientAddr,
          (socklen_t*) &clientAddrSize);
      close(serverSocket);

      exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it through GDB?

Comment: You don't check the return value when you call send().  Without checking the return value, you have no way to know whether send() succeeded or failed.  (if you find out that send() failed, then check the value of errno afterwards to find out why it failed)

Comment: `when I receive wrong user& passwd,it doesn't do anything!!!` -- How do you know it is not doing anything? Is `send(sock, &login, strlen(login) + 1, 0);` never received on the other end? Have you checked the return of `send`?

Comment: This program is missing both semicolons and closing braces and wouldn't even compile. Therefore, you're clearly not you're showing us the exact version of the source code that's actually running. The minutest mistake could cause an error, so it is important that you post the source *exactly* as it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C's printf and fprintf(stdout,) are not printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784367/cs-printf-and-fprintfstdout-are-not-printing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly problem in your client. Even if passwd is wrong your wait for the another connection (accept in else). You should post your client code as well.

Comment: THX!! I find the key in client Server.

Answer (score 0):

After having sent out "wrong" the code gets stuck in this line:

```
  sock = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*) &clientAddr,
      (socklen_t*) &clientAddrSize);
```

Just remove it, it is uselessly waiting for another incoming connection.

Comment: The exact same thing is in the other branch of the `if`, but the author claims it's working.

Comment: @n.m: I suspect the client just connects again in this case. But this and other things are different stories though ...

Answer (score 0):

One massive problem with this is that after you test the credentials string, both clauses close serverSocket, this means that after two wrong tries of username#password, the server won't accept any more connections anyway!

The next problem is that the recv call isn't within the while loop, so the server will only read the login string once, after that it won't read any more attempts until it has been restarted.

Yet another problem is that both clauses of the if/else structure exit the program, so the while(1) is redundant, and so is the accept() call in the second clause.

In the "Correct" clause, you accept another connection, and read a string from it... not from the connection that has been authernticated by the username#password.

These aren't the bugs you're asking about, but they still render the program unreliable.
So before you do anything:

- declare an int called "finished", which is initially set to zero;
- replace while(1){} with do{}while(!finished);
- move the accept() and recv() calls into the do-while loop, just before the if/strcmp test
- remove the exit() calls, replace the one in the "correct" clause with finished=1;
- remove the accept() call from both the "correct" and "incorrect" clauses
- close serverSocket after the do-while loop.
  As other responders have said, you also need to capture and check the return values from send() and recv(), it wouldn't hurt to check the return value of accept either.

By The Way, if you must use recv() with strings, you probably want to use strncmp(), you captured recv() return value as "len", why haven't you tested this to see that recv did something?